# How to output "X years, Y months and Z days" using date_diff?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

How can I create a human readable date difference string using **PHP**?

**Examples:**

- X day(s)
- X month(s)
- X day(s) and Y month(s)
- X year(s), Y month(s) and Z day(s)

`date_diff` doesn't seem to support this, at least not in the required detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes two timestamps and converts them to a format that is readable.

- It returns only the parts (years/months/days) that are **> 0**
- It considers singular and plural for year(s), month(s) and day(s)
- It concatinates with **","** and with **"and"**, depending on how many items are displayed

**Examples:**

- 1 day ago
- 3 days ago
- 1 month and 3 days ago
- 3 months and 1 day ago
- 1 year and 5 days ago
- 2 years, 10 months and 16 days ago
- 2 years and 1 day ago

---

```
public static function FormatTimeSpan($time1, $time2)
{
    $diff = date_diff(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time1)), new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time2)));

    $items = [ ];
    if ($diff->y > 0) $items[] = $diff->y == 1 ? '1 year' : $diff->y . ' years';
    if ($diff->m > 0) $items[] = $diff->m == 1 ? '1 month' : $diff->m . ' months';
    if ($diff->d > 0) $items[] = $diff->d == 1 ? '1 day' : $diff->d . ' days';
    if (count($items) == 0) $items[] = '0 days';

    $last = array_pop($items);
    return count($items) == 0 ? $last : implode(', ', $items) . ' and ' . $last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I had to modify the vars $time1 by strtotime($time1) and $time2 by strtotime($time2) too. Then I tried some dates and got the same result as my function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I did a function some time ago.

```
/**
 * Calculate the time between two dates
 * If the second date is not specified it takes the current day
 * @author rsalcedo
 * @param date ("Y-m-d") (aaaa-mm-dd) $from
 * @param date ("Y-m-d") (aaaa-mm-dd) $to
 */
function years_months_days($from,$to="") {
    try {
        $myFrom = new DateTime($from);
        $myAcarreo = 0;
        if ($to=="" || null)
            $to=date("Y-m-d");
            $myTo = new DateTime($to);
            $diff_year = $myTo->format("Y") - $myFrom->format("Y") ;
            $diff_mnth = $myTo->format("m") - $myFrom->format("m") ;
            $diff_days = $myTo->format("d") - $myFrom->format("d") ;

            if ($diff_days<0){
                $diff_days = $diff_days + 30;
                $myAcarreo = -1;
            }
            $diff_mnth = $diff_mnth + $myAcarreo;
            $myAcarreo = 0;
            if ($diff_mnth<0){
                $diff_mnth = $diff_mnth + 12;
                $myAcarreo = -1;
            }
            $diff_year = $diff_year + $myAcarreo;
            return array($diff_year,$diff_mnth,$diff_days);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

You can use this way:

```
list($edad,$edadMes,$edadDias) = years_months_days("1979-09-12");
echo "$edad years, $edadMes months, $edadDias days.";

list($edad,$edadMes,$edadDias) = years_months_days("1979-09-12","2008-07-18");
echo "$edad years, $edadMes months, $edadDias days.";
```

Improvements are welcome!

Comment: This function doesn't cut out zeroes. Outputs could also be "0 years, 0 months, 1 days". And it doesn't handle singular/plural. Also assuming that a month has 30 days could be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is tested.

```
$date1 = date_create("2017-11-27");
$date2 = date_create("2018-12-29");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$months = $diff->format("%m months");
$years = $diff->format("%y years");
$days = $diff->format("%d days");

echo $years .' '.$months.' '.$days;
```

the output is:

```
1 years 1 months 2 days
```

Comment: This will also return "0 years 0 months 0 days", for insance. Have a look at my answer to see concatenation logic.